# need to change the data type for distribution key from Integer to bigint

Tags: netezza

Is there any way we can change the data type of a distribution key from INT to BIGINT ? Or create a new field, and make it the new distribution key  ???

Answer (score 4):

You will have to drop the table and rebuild.  The reason you can't alter the distribution columns in place is they have to be physically implemented on the disk.

```
create table new_table as
select cast(id as bigint) as id
,other fields
from orginal_table
distribute on (id)

drop table orginal_table

alter table new_table rename to orginal_table
```